# Parallel hyperparameter optimization with pytorch on a multi-gpu machine

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, hyperparameters, multi-gpu

I have access to a multi-gpu machine and I am running a grid search loop for parameter optimisation. I would like to know if I can distribute several iterations of the loop on multiple gpu at the same time, and if so how do I do it (what me mechanism? threading? how to gather the results if the loop execute asynchronously? etc.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using [Optuna](https://optuna.org/) to handle hyper-parameters search, which should in general perform better than grid search (you can still use it with grid sampling though). I have modified Optuna [distributed example](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/distributed.html) to use one GPU per process.

1. Create a training script like:

```py
# optimize.py

import sys
import optuna
import your_model


DEVICE = 'cuda:' + sys.argv[1]

def objective(trial):
    hidden_size = trial.suggest_int('hidden_size', 8, 64, log=True)
    # define other hyperparameters

    return your_model.score(hidden_size=hidden_size, device=DEVICE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    study = optuna.load_study(study_name='distributed-example', storage='sqlite:///example.db')
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)
```

2. In terminal:

```sh
pip install optuna
optuna create-study --study-name "distributed-example" --storage "sqlite:///example.db"
```

3. Then for every GPU device:

```sh
python optimize.py 0
python optimize.py 1
...
```

4. Finally, best results can be easily discovered:

```py
import optuna

study = optuna.create_study(study_name='distributed-example', storage='sqlite:///example.db', load_if_exists=True)

print(study.best_params)
print(study.best_value)
```

Or even [visualized](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/visualization.html).